# disable clicking on javascript element beneath mask

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, css

I have the following problem;

I have a circle (square div made round with css3) where I want to put a clickable Google Maps map in it. So what I did is;

- load the Google Maps element in my page
- give the div where Google Maps is loaded in a mask

> -webkit-mask-image: url(../images/maps_mask.png);
>       -webkit-mask-repeat: no-repeat;

looks great! but when i click in the corners (which are hided because of the mask) I can still drag the Google Maps map around ! 
And I don't want this!

Is there a simple solution for this?

kind regards,
Carl

Comment: will u please paste code or image??

Answer (score 0):

You could try to catch all mouse-events that land onto the google map, calculate (by position) if the hit is outside of the visible area and cancel them if they do.